# Database error: relation does not exist

Tags: java

I have a postgres database and a table named "state_master". I'm simply fetching the data from this table by the following code.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Test1 
{     

     public static void main(String... s1)
    {
        try{

                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:secc_db","postgres", password");
                Statement s = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("Select * from state_master");


               }catch(SQLException e){  System.out.println(e);}

                catch(Exception i){System.out.println(i);}

        }
      }
```

All I get is an error: `relation state_master does not exist`. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Please format your code in a way that is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

The erroe means the table state_master is not exist in the user(Database) postgres. Check whether you have created the table state_master in your database or not. If not first create the table then try to execute the program.

Comment: yes i have the table in my database 
i have checked it 100 times

Comment: nd name is also the same "state_master".

Comment: i found the problem.
when i m writing the connection string 
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:secc_db","postgres", "nic@123"); 

the controller dont go into the database that i have specified but goes to the default database which is named postgres
but i dnt knw why it is happing...

Answer (score 1):

Your connect url is not correct. you are using colon(:) for specifying the database.
It should be a slash(/) like : `"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/secc_db"`